# Different pipe size between Ubuntu and Debian

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, debian, pipe

I was testing file transfer with OpenBSD netcat and noticed that it takes a bit more time to transfer the same file on Ubuntu rather than Debian. Using strace, I found that data is transferred in 64k blocks on Ubuntu.

```
mgamal@ubuntu:~$ strace cat test | nc -vvvv 10.10.172.11 8888
...

read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536

write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536

read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536

write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536

read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536

write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 65536) = 65536
```

On Debian on the other hand:

```
mgamal@ubuntu:~$ strace cat test | nc -vvvv 10.10.172.11 8888
....
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
```

I wrote the following piece of code on Debian to check the pipe size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int pipefd[2];
    int size;
    int i;

    pipefd[0] = STDIN_FILENO;
    pipefd[1] = STDOUT_FILENO;

    pipe(pipefd);

    size = fcntl(pipefd[0], F_GETPIPE_SZ);

    printf("%d\n", size);

    size = fcntl(pipefd[1], F_GETPIPE_SZ);

    printf("%d\n", size);

    return 0;
 }
```

Running it, it still reports 64k

```
mgamal@debian:~$ ./test
65536
65536
```

I also tried using something other than netcat to check. And I still see the pipe size being 128k

```
root@debian:~# strace cat foo | less
...
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
```

I've tried to check the source packages for netcat, the kernel, glibc to see if the pipe size is set to 128k, or if there are any calls to fcntl() that change the pipe size, but could find no trace.

Why is the pipe size reported as 64k, while actual size is 128k?

Comment: Part of an answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer. OSX pipes are reported as dynamically changing the size on *big* writes... Did you tried to get the size at different times during the sending?

Comment: I ran the script in the answer on both Ubuntu and Debian. Both report 64k, and 0 bytes are written in writes that exceed 64k.

Comment: I've downloaded the bash source package in debian, and again saw no fcntl() calls.

Comment: I've also removed the pipe() call from the program. Ran: `date | ./test | tee foo` and still got 64k on Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU cat is in the coreutils package. GNU cat does a `stat` or `fstat` on its input and output and looks at `st_blksize`, the optimal blocksize for filesystem I/O.  It then takes the max of that number and a hardwired number and uses that as the buffer size for input and output. This is done in [io_blksize](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ioblksize.h).

Ubuntu 14 comes with coreutils 8.21. The minimum blocksize in [that version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ioblksize.h?id=v8.21) is 64KiB.

Debian 8 comes with coreutils 8.23. The minimum blocksize in [that version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ioblksize.h?id=v8.23) is 128KiB.